How do you mount your physical hard drive to VirtualBox?
I have a physical two terabyte laptop hard drive that I want access. The hard drive itself contains a Windows 10 Home OS that used to belong to an HP 15-da0061cl notebook. I used to own that notebook but it broke down and removed the hard drive. I heard that VirtualBox can access a physical drive and I want to try it.
I already a USB Sabrent HDD adaptor and enclosure to use with VirtualBox. The problem is that I do not know how to do it. How do you mount your physical drive with VirtualBox? How do you access your old OS through VirtualBox to use a Virtual Machine? And is it advisable to do it?

Assuming you already have VirtualBox installed, and a VM in it with an OS on it.
Make sure you install the extension pack for your current version of VirtualBox if you haven't previously done so. Also make sure you have the guest addons installed inside the OS.
If you have the OS booted, turn off the VM and plug in the harddisk.
Modify the Guest VM, go to the USB tab and ensure the USB controller is enabled (this is enabled by default), then press the usb plug with a green + to mount the USB device. This step can also be done while the VM is running, from the menu.
Boot the OS and the disk should be accessible now.
And yes, there is no reason not to do this. Keep in mind that any action you perform in the guest OS will be done directly to the disk as if it was plugged in your own computer.

This will allow me to boot the OS and use it from the USB drive?

If that OS is on the USB drive, no. Windows does not allow booting from a removable drive.

@GAP while you can boot a Windows installation on a USB HDD/SSD, you'd probably have problem booting an existing one (i.e. installation not completed "in USB") because the host bus type change (SATA/AHCI -> USB/UAS). If you really need to boot it in the VM, you may have a better chance doing it with the raw VMDK approach, with the semi-emulated drive connected to an emulated SATA/AHCI controller (assuming it is not an M.2 NVMe drive).

So much for booting from the USB. I will have to make that VMDK file but what is a good way to make that file in Windows 10?

You can make it a vhdx using disk2vhd, a tool you can download from microsoft. It'll work in VirtualBox too, and that, you can boot from.

@GAP https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk
